# Getting an error while calling GET /system/ping

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am getting an error while calling GET /system/ping

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "error trying login and get user Context. Error: error trying to enroll user. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]",
  }
}
```

I have made the participant

```
Blockchain Participant
{ 
  '$class': 'org.optum.blockchainv5.Participant',
  ParticipantId: 'ParticipantId:2',
  Name: 'Vipul Bajaj' 
}
```

Then issued an identity to the participant

```
System Identity
{ 
  userID: 'ParticipantId:2', 
  userSecret: 'dPJbJBsaOLaf' 
}
```

And then added that identity to default wallet

```
Wallet Identity
{ 
  enrollmentID: 'ParticipantId:2',
  enrollmentSecret: 'dPJbJBsaOLaf',
  id: 3 
}
```

And then set this wallet identity default by calling the `POST /wallets/1/identities/3/setDefault`

Got response code 204

And after calling `GET system/ping` gave me error.

Answer (score 0):

just following up - if you're still getting this error, could you attach a trace log setting export DEBUG=composer:* ` then re-running the rest server - the log file is in a 'logs' directory (from where you start the composer-rest-server). Then we can see what's going on with the POST.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I was trying to deploy a **composer hlfv1** network instance locally. I was running the `./createComposerProfile.sh` script. This script has this line `cp "${DIR}"/hlfv1/composer/creds/* ~/.hfc-key-store`
This copies all the credentials on your creds folder and overrides the ones created by `composer identity import` on your `~/.hfc-key-store`
You could **copy** the credentials from ~/.hfc-key-store to the creds folder **or** comment out this line.

Comment: Actually I also solved the problem in the same manner.Thanks @Esther